# ASP.NET Confirmation dialog on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Page which takes input from the user and then process his request on a button click.
On this button click event, I need to validate the input entered by him and on certain condition show confirmation dialog box.
If he clicks Yes, then I need to perform further action else return.

I have tried using

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Constants.OpenConfirm, "confirm('Data Already Exists, do you Wish to Overwrite the existing record?')", true);
```

But irrespective of whether I click Yes or No it is performing the further action.

Have have tried using JavaScript method calling from server side, but that is also not working out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the result of your confirm call. So the script parameter musts be something like that:

```
if(!confirm('Data Already Exists, do you Wish to Overwrite the existing record?')) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
Server side code

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", "Javascript:val()", true);
```

client side code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function val() {
            if (confirm('XXXXYYYY?')) { alert("clicked yes") } else { alert("clicked No") }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on page_load .cs

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", 
"javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {  alert('YOu have selected YES')} else{alert('you have click NO')}; ", true);
```